# Set #include directory from C++ code file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In MSVC++ you can always do

```
#pragma comment( lib, "libname.lib" )
```

TO link a library in from a code file, instead of fiddling with the project options dialog.

I'm looking for a way to add "Additional Include Directories" *from the code file* instead of using `Project Settings/Configuration Properties/C,C++/General/Additional Include Directories`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.  If you already know where the header is stored when you write the code then you should include the path in the #include directive.