# Is there a way to add include directory from C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I have a project whose vcxproj file is auto generated prior of compilation by using a script during the build process.

this project dependes on a boost library which is installed in a known location on the build machine.

the project header file declares:

```
#include "boost/foreach.hpp"
```

which forces me to manually add the path to the `boost` root folder to the `Additional Include Directories` field in the vcxproj file.

As the project file is auto-generated it forces me to split the build process into two stages and edit the project file in between.

i have also tried to change the source file and add the full path in the `#include` statement:

```
#include "<path to boost root>/boost/foreach.hpp"
```

but then some `boost` internal include fails. Which means i can't proceed in this way.

I have read through [Set #include directory from C++ code file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828746/set-include-directory-from-c-code-file) to find there is no option to add the path from code.

As I'm now on VS2012/C++11 environment i wonder if anything changed in VS2012 / C++11?

Is it still impossible to add an Include directory using a code statement?

Comment: Maybe it's possible with some kind of #pragma, but I doubt this. Why don't you change the generation of the vcxproj file, to add the include directory?

Comment: `#include "<path to boost root>"` is usually done adding `/I <path to boost root>` in your compiler options.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - i use `devenv mySolution.sln Release /rebuild` command line - should i simply add `/I <path to boost root>`?

Comment: if you are auto-generating the `vcxproj` via some script or other tool, why can't you add the path to Boost at the time of generation?

Comment: @NirMH No, I don't think you can pass compiler switches to `devenv`. Get your build script to generate the *vcxproj* with the correct settings. Another option is to have the build machine set an environment variable, say `BOOST_ROOT`, that points to the boost installation directory. You can reference that within the vcxproj as `$(BOOST_ROOT)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, doing this:

`#include "<path to boost root>/boost/foreach.hpp"`

should be strongly discouraged. By doing that, you're making your source code build-able only on your environment - as your project grows, it will be a nightmare to change the path, or for other developers to build it. And, as you discovered, you'll break any headers which are included further down the chain, which are using relative paths.

What kind of script is generating your project? Is it a custom one, or is it a well known build tool such as SCons or CMake? The correct solution is to fix your build script so that it generates the project with the additional include paths correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - looks like the only way is to modify the build script - which is btw a custom script - not using CMake or SCons...

Answer (score 1):

You mean dynamically? No, there is no way. The reason is simple:

When you are running your program, it's already compiled, hence the compiler has to know about all the files to include at compile time.

It seems you're using `CMake`. If that's the case, I recommend you to add the include dirs in the `CMake` file.